# str.replace starting from the back in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have two columns like so:

```
                                       string                    s
0    the best new york cheesecake new york ny             new york
1               houston public school houston              houston
```

I want to remove the last occurrence of `s` in `string`. For context, my DataFrame has hundreds of thousands of rows. I know about `str.replace` and `str.rfind`, but nothing that does the desired combination of both, and I'm coming up blank in improvising a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rsplit` and `join`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['string'].rsplit(x['s'],1)),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    the best new york cheesecake  ny
1              houston public school 
dtype: object
```

edit:

```
df['string'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['string'].rsplit(x['s'],1)),axis=1).str.replace('\s\s',' ')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            string         s  third
0  the best new york cheesecake ny  new york      1
1           houston public school    houston      1
```

Comment: Very nice.  Could you add a `replace` or a similar function to get rid of the double space left after the split if the last occurrence is in the middle of the string?

Comment: @vealkind Yes.  `df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['string'].rsplit(x['s'],1)),axis=1).str.replace('\s\s',' ')`

Comment: I added a third column and this seems to keep only the `string` column. Is there a way to preserve other columns as well?

Comment: My pleasure.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Vectorized `rsplit` with a comprehension

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import rsplit

v = df.string.values.astype(str)
s = df.s.values.astype(str)

df.assign(string=[' '.join([x.strip() for x in y]) for y in rsplit(v, s, 1)])

                            string         s
0  the best new york cheesecake ny  new york
1           houston public school    houston
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `re.sub`
The regex here looks for the values from `s` that isn't followed by another of the same value.

```
import re

v = df.string.values.astype(str)
s = df.s.values.astype(str)
f = lambda i, j: re.sub(r' *{0} *(?!.*{0}.*)'.format(i), ' ', j).strip()

df.assign(string=[f(i, j) for i, j in zip(s, v)])

                            string         s
0  the best new york cheesecake ny  new york
1            houston public school   houston
```